# Intellij IDEA: Couldn't get the list of GitHub repositories

Tags: github, intellij-idea, github-api

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1 on Win7 and want to checkout a GitHub project using the build in wizzard. Unfortunatly i get the following error:

> Couldn't get the list of GitHub repositories,
>   Can't get available repositories Method Not Allowed
>
> [image: Checkout from GitHub]

I configured my proxy settings and my GitHub username and password. Did i forget something?

EDIT:
When i test the connection under *IntelliJ setting -> Version Control> GitHub* i get the following error:

> Can't login: Can't get user info
>   Method Not Allowed

Comment: Did you solve this by now? Encountering a similar problem.

Comment: I worked around it by using an other internet access point, that was not behind a proxy.

Comment: not sure that I follow. In the settings I get "Connection successful", but when trying to checkout (VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Github) I get the Couldn't get the list of GitHub repositories error...

Comment: Same issue ! Can't login: Connect to api.github.com:443 [api.github.com/192.30.253.116] failed: connect timed out. Tests the same URL with proxy are successfull.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and this is how I solved it

1. Click on configure then select settings (or `Preferences` menu on the Mac)
2. Select `Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy`
3. Check the radio button Manual proxy configuration
4. Enter your Host IP in the host name and the port number in the port number position
5. Click check connection and enter a url e.g [github](http://github.com) to test if the proxy setting works
6. Click Ok
7. Click on checkout from version control to pull from git